# Rows not getting displayed when implemented with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Empty Rows are getting added in the table but the row values are not reflecting after entering values in modal popup form.

This is the html snippet wherein i have already added ng-controller="compctrl" .

```
<!-- BEGIN CONTAINER -->
<div class="page-container">

    <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
    <div class="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="page-content" ng-controller="compctrl">
            <!-- BEGIN SAMPLE PORTLET CONFIGURATION MODAL FORM-->

            <!-- /.modal -->
            <!-- END SAMPLE PORTLET CONFIGURATION MODAL FORM-->
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE HEADER-->
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE HEAD -->
            <div class="page-head">
                <!-- BEGIN PAGE TITLE -->
                <div class="page-title">
                    <h1>Deep discounts</h1>
                </div>
                <!-- END PAGE TITLE -->
                <!-- BEGIN PAGE TOOLBAR -->

                <!-- END PAGE TOOLBAR -->
            </div>
            <!-- END PAGE HEAD -->
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE BREADCRUMB -->
            <ul class="page-breadcrumb breadcrumb">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Discounts</a>
                    <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Deep Discounts</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- END PAGE BREADCRUMB -->
            <!-- END PAGE HEADER-->
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT-->
            <div class="clearfix">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary green pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add new field</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" >
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Discount</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="addRow()">

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="name">
                                            <span class="help-block">A block of help text. </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Strength</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter number" ng-model="strength">
                                            <span class="help-block">A block of help number. </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Location</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text" ng-model="location">
                                            <span class="help-block">A block of help text. </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                       <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                                        </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
            </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="portlet box blue-hoki">
                        <div class="portlet-title">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>Datatable with TableTools
                            </div>
                            <div class="tools">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="portlet-body">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="sample_1">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                     Name
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                     Strength
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                     Location
                                </th>

                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="company in companies">
                                   <td>{{company.name}}
                                         </td>
                                   <td>{{company.strength}}
                                        </td>
                                   <td>{{company.location}}
                                               </td>
                             </tr>

                            </tbody>
                            </table>
                    </div>
                     </div>


                    <!-- END EXAMPLE TABLE PORTLET-->
                </div>
            </div></div>



        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- END CONTENT -->

<!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

This is the app.js state provider context:

```
.state('myDatatablesAdvanced', {
            url: "/datatables/deepdiscount1",
            templateUrl: "views/datatables/deepdiscount1.html",
            data: {pageTitle: 'Advanced Datatables', pageSubTitle: 'advanced datatables samples'},
            controller: "compctrl",
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'MetronicApp',
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before '#ng_load_plugins_before'
                        files: [
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/select2/select2.css',                             
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.css', 
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/Scroller/css/dataTables.scroller.min.css',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/ColReorder/css/dataTables.colReorder.min.css',

                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/select2/select2.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/datatables/all.min.js',

                            'js/scripts/table-advanced.js',

                            'js/controllers/tab.js'
                        ]
                    });
                }]
            }
        })
```

and this is the custom controller "compctrl" that i created to add values in the table.

```
MetronicApp.controller('compctrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'settings', function($rootScope, $scope, settings) {
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {

        $scope.companies = [
                    { 'name':'Infosys Technologies',
                        'strength': 125000,
                        'location': 'Bangalore'},
                        { 'name':'Cognizant Technologies',
                            'strength': 100000,
                            'location': 'Bangalore'},
                            { 'name':'Wipro',
                                'strength': 115000,
                                'location': 'Bangalore'},
                                { 'name':'Tata Consultancy Services (TCS)',
                                    'strength': 150000,
                                    'location': 'Bangalore'},
                                    { 'name':'HCL Technologies',
                                        'strength': 90000,
                                        'location': 'Noida'},
                    ];
$scope.addRow = function(){     
    $scope.companies.push({ 'name':$scope.name, 'strength': $scope.strength, 'location':$scope.location });
    $scope.name='';
    $scope.strength='';
    $scope.location='';
};

        // initialize core components
        Metronic.initAjax();


    });
}]);
```

I want to inform that i am using Metronic Theme.But When i input values in modal form ,its not getting added in a row.Only empty rows are appearing.

Comment: it could be due to the fact that you are clearing $scope.name, $scope.strength, and $scope.location. Try putting the values into a var first and use that to assign it.  `var name = $scope.name; $scope.companies.push({'name':name});`

Comment: It is not working .Kindly give me an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of the scope issue of the controller(template) and the modal. Try using $rootscope or try broadcasting the values from the modal to the controller and then push it into $scope.companies from the controller.